# Trouble with Phonebook

Tags: php

I want to create a digital phonebook where i can add / delete entries. I can add without a problem, but when i try to delete an entry (per radio boxes), always the last entry of the session array is gone ...

phonebook: (index.php)

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>2PLF</title>
  <style>
   table{
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
   }
   table, table tr, table tr td{
    border: 0.1rem solid #444;
   }
   table tr th{
    border: 0.2rem solid #444;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form method="post">
  <h1>My phonebook</h1>

  <?php
  if(isset($_POST["add"])){
   header("location:new.php");
  }
  if(isset($_SESSION["new"])){
  
   foreach($_SESSION["new"] as $number => $name){
    $_SESSION["phonebook"][$number] = $name;
   }
   
   //clean up
   unset($_SESSION["new"]);
   
  }
  
  if(isset($_SESSION["phonebook"])){
   ?>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <th>Number</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach($_SESSION["phonebook"] as $number => $name){
     echo '<tr>
     <td>'.$number.'</td>
     <td>'.$name.'</td>
     <td><input type="radio" name="radio"></td>
     </tr>';
     
    }
    
    if(isset($_POST["delete"]) && isset($_POST["radio"])){
     
      unset($_SESSION["phonebook"][$number]);
      header("location:index.php");
      
    }else if(isset($_POST["delete"]) && !isset($_POST["radio"])){
      echo "Please check your Input";
    }
    
    ?>
   </table>
   <?php
   
  }
  ?>
   <input name="add" type="submit" value="Add a new number">
   <input name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete an entry">
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

add an entry (new.php)

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>2PLF</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 
  <h1>Add an entry</h1>
  
  <?php
   $success = false;
   if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["number"])){
    $success = true;
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $number = $_POST["number"];
    
    $newEntry = array(
     $number => $name,
    );
    
    //put the array in a session array
    $_SESSION["new"] = $newEntry;
    
   }
  ?>
  
  <form method="post">
   <input name="name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Name">
   <input name="number" type="text" value="" placeholder="Phone number">
   <input type="submit" value="Add entry">
  </form>
  
  <?php 
  if($success == true){
   if($name == "" || $number == ""){
    echo "Please enter a valid name and number";
   }else{
    header("location:index.php");
   }
  }
  ?>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Please note, that all radio boxes must have the same name.
I know, that there is a little piece of wrong code somewehere in the index.php, but i cant find ...

Thanks !

Comment: Header cannot work because an output has already been sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the identity of the record with radio.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="'.$number.'">
```

Comment: oh thanks, i cant beleve that i forgot to do this :)